# How can I read the hop count/TTL of an UDP packet I got through a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, ip, posix

I use recvfrom() on a UDP socket to get my data, but is there some way to parse the corresponding IP header so I can see how many hops the packet has traveled?

Comment: You have to use raw sockets to get the IP header.

Comment: But this would require root privileges and bypassing the IP stack. What if I receive UDP packets that are not on my port number?